# Getting illegal character when sending GET request in JMETER. Working fine in browser

Tags: api, jmeter

Im getting illegal character in JMETER for GET request -
https://dev1/api/v1/query/job/?filter={%22job_manager_id%22:%22553f2350-12d3-4252-8fe0-39691019c495%22}
tried replacing %22 with "" but still getting illegal character.
Any solutions ?

Comment: Could you please also post the browser request screenshot or details. Only posting part of the question won't help the community to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think problematic characters are `{` and `}`, they need to be [percent-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

The options are in:

1. Tick "URL-encode" box next to the `filter` parameter in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler :

   [image]
2. Use [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) in "Path" field like

   [image]

   see [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept
3. Or just hard-code the percent-encoded Path part like:

   ```
   https://dev1/api/v1/query/job/?filter=%7B%22job_manager_id%22%3A%22553f2350-12d3-4252-8fe0-39691019c495%22%7D
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T